# WAP to find whether a string is palindrome or not in C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace PelindromeIdentifier
  {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
        int nNumberOfTestCases = 0;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nNumberOfTestCases);

        String[] strTestCases = new String[nNumberOfTestCases];
        char[] arrChar;
        int nCharCount = 0;
        bool bAllow = false;
        int nCharIndex = 0;

        for (int nTestCase = 0; nTestCase < nNumberOfTestCases; nTestCase++)
        {
            strTestCases[nTestCase] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (int nTestCase = 0; nTestCase < nNumberOfTestCases; nTestCase++)
        {
            bAllow = false;

            arrChar = strTestCases[nTestCase].Distinct().ToArray();

            for (nCharIndex = 0; nCharIndex < arrChar.Length; nCharIndex++)
            {
          nCharCount = strTestCases[nTestCase].Count(i =>                                     i.Equals(arrChar[nCharIndex]));

                if (strTestCases[nTestCase].Length % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if (nCharCount % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("NO");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (nCharCount % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        if (bAllow == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("NO");
                            break;
                        }
                        bAllow = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (nCharIndex == arrChar.Length)
            {`
                Console.WriteLine("YES");
            }
            }
            }
           }
              }
```

I tried this but there are some hidden test cases which are not working.Can anybody help me?In this program the program will ask user how many times you want to take input string and for every string it will return whether the string is palindrome or not

Comment: possible duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790749/check-if-a-string-is-a-palindrome

Comment: Just help what would be the possible test cases

Comment: Hidden test cases? Seriously?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with your code. Are you actually trying to make your code as dufficult to understand as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you mean by possible test cases:
I've changed your code and tested with 3 strings :

"coucou" : not palindrome

"kayak" : palindrome

"abcdeffedcba" : palindrome

and it works fine now:

[image: palindrome]

```
 static void Main()
    {
        int nNumberOfTestCases = 0;
        var input = 
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nNumberOfTestCases);

        String[] strTestCases = new String[nNumberOfTestCases];

        for (int nTestCase = 0; nTestCase < nNumberOfTestCases; nTestCase++)
        {
            strTestCases[nTestCase] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (int nTestCase = 0; nTestCase < nNumberOfTestCases; nTestCase++)
        {

            if (strTestCases[nTestCase].SequenceEqual(strTestCases[nTestCase].Reverse()))
                Console.WriteLine("YES");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("NO");


        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: what would happen if we take empty string as a input?

Comment: if we take empty string as input it will return YES, but if you prefer it to return no in this special case , you can modify this line :     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTestCases[nTestCase]) && strTestCases[nTestCase].SequenceEqual(strTestCases[nTestCase].Reverse()))