# How to check case-sensitive words if they are palindrome

Tags: c#

I made a program which is checking if a word is a palindrome.

But if I type "Lol" it says that's palindrome.

I think palindrome must be completly same. ?

```
 public static bool IsPalindrome(string text)
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = text.Length - 1;

            while (true)
            {
                if (min > max)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                char a = text[min];
                char b = text[max];

                if (char.ToLower(a) != char.ToLower(b))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                min++;
                max--;
            }
        }
```

Input: "Lol"
Output: "Lol is NOT a palindrome"

Comment: Well you do check whether `char.ToLower(a) != char.ToLower(b)`, so obviously it's case-insensitive. What's your actual question?

Comment: How to make it case-sensitive

Comment: Remove the call to `ToLower`.

Comment: I showed you the code which makes it case-insensitive. To make it case-insensitive, change that bit of code so it is not case-insensitive... I really don't understand where you're coming from - you said you wrote this code, and you explicitly went out of your way to add logic to make it case-insensitive. Now you're asking how to change this...

Comment: @canton7 Perhaps he did write the code but did not understand what the `ToLower()` function does when looking on the internet.

Comment: @bradbury9 I don't understand why he added it if he had no understanding of it. I think it's probably more likely he lied about writing the code...

Comment: If he is not english or does not understand english, perhaps copied the character comparision without noticing it did not do what he expected to do. Kinda weird, I agree, but not impossible

Comment: @canton7 If I wanted to copy the could I could do it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790749/check-if-a-string-is-a-palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790749/check-if-a-string-is-a-palindrome) here easily

Answer (score 0):

To make your method case-sensitive, you should remove the calls to [ToLower()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.tolower?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Char_ToLower_System_Char_):

```
while (true)
{
    if (min > max)
    {
        return true;
    }

    char a = text[min];
    char b = text[max];

    if (a != b)
    {
        return false;
    }

    min++;
    max--;
}
```

The "Lol" won't be considered as a palindrome but "LoL" will.

Comment: Thank you, I can't tick the answer yet.

Comment: I would encourage checking the [char.Tower() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.tolower?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Char_ToLower_System_Char_) to fully understand the reason.